# Application load balancer without a target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I would like to have a load balancer just for collecting raw data. I would like to save the access logs to an s3 bucket, and no need to have any taget associated with the load balancer. is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can have empty target group.